# How to define custom animations for noUislider.js?

Tags: javascript, css, nouislider

I implemented the noUiSlider into my website which is just awesome.

1. However, I would like to define my own custom animations for the handlers/slider. Does anyone know which DOM elements I have to target in order to make the slider update `aria` and what is possible and what is not to avoid crushing the lib?
2. When I follow the documentation and set animation to true and alter the `webkit-animation` manually for `.noUi-state-tap, .noUi-origin` the animation doesn't take the time I set it to. I debugged it in the browser and it seems it doesn't apply the css-props, even though I highlighted them as `!important`. It just fires and animates the `set` function (upon button click) in a blink of an eye.

Any solution to this?

**Slider**

```
// javascript

function initialSlider() {

    clearInputs ();

    var slider = document.getElementById("slider");

    // Define values
    var initialPrice = 77.99;
    var maxRangeSlider = initialPrice * 4;
    var startBottomSlider = maxRangeSlider/4;
    var startInitialSlider = maxRangeSlider/4;
    var startTopSlider = maxRangeSlider/4;

    // Create slider itself

    noUiSlider.create(slider, {
        animate: true,
        animationDuration: 300,
        start: [startBottomSlider, startInitialSlider, startTopSlider],
        connect: [false, true, true, true],
        range: {
            'min': [0],
            '15%': [initialPrice * 0.85],
            '85%': [initialPrice * 1.15],
            'max': [maxRangeSlider]
        }
    });

    var connect = slider.querySelectorAll('.noUi-connect');
    var classes = ['c-1-color', 'c-2-color', 'c-3-color', 'c-4-color'];

    for (var i = 0; i < connect.length; i++) {
        connect[i].classList.add(classes[i]);
    }
[..]
```

```
// CSS

.noUi-state-tap, .noUi-origin {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 50ms !important;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 300ms !important;
}
```

```
// javascript set function trigger

const slider = document.getElementById("slider");
slider.noUiSlider.set([66.29, null, 89.69]);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your styling `.noUi-state-tap, .noUi-origin` is targeting two selectors, `.noUi-state-tap` and `.noUi-origin`. Neither of those is [specific](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) enough to override the default styling. You should remove the comma (`,`), like so:

```
.noUi-state-tap .noUi-connect,
.noUi-state-tap .noUi-origin {
-webkit-transition: transform 0.3s; // Change this to the desired duration
    transition: transform 0.3s;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I am getting close to it. Now the handles move just fine, but the colored connections are ahead of time. How to come about this? (it is tough to rebuild a MWE, this is the live slider: https://www.cfd-manager.com/).

Comment: You only overrode the styling for `.noUi-origin`. You should do the same for `.noUi-connect` (see the snippet in the answer).